# Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Tags: php, security, symfony, object, symfony-security

I am using a vote with symfony to deal with user access on my site.
When the user is not authenticated I get the error :

```
Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
```

when the user is accessing a page where a voter is called.
The code in the voter trigerring the issue is :

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
if (!$object || !$this->supportsClass(get_class($object))) {
    return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
}
...}
```

when the object = 'anon.' and this is the regular code taken from symfony website.
I can of course modify this code to check for wether the object is an object or not but I was wondering if this was normal? I would have hopped that a voter would not be called on a non object.

EDIT:
SuportsClass and SupportsAttribute are also the default ones:

```
protected function getSupportedClasses()
{
    return array(
        'AppBundle\Entity\User\Associate',
    );
}

protected function getSupportedAttributes()
{
    return array(self::SELECT_ASSOCIATES, self::GRANT_RIGHTS, self::REMOVE_RIGHT, self::DISPLAY_RIGHTS);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `supportsAttribute()` and `supportsClass()` ?  I'm wondering if you are properly checking that the object is of the appropriate type there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user isn't logged in, but the access control allows anonymous users, the user is a string "anon." instead of a UserInterface instance.

You should put a check into `supportsClass` (e.g. `return is_object($objec);`).

Comment: well, as you can see in my code (the default code from symfony), the suprotsClass is given a class argument, so the get_class is called before the check might be done. So I believe we just have to add the check in the vote method or restrict the route to connected users...